# Determine whether the argument is valid or invalid

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$\displaylines{
¬p → (r ∧ ¬s)\cr
t → s\cr
u → ¬p\cr
¬w\cr
u ∨ w\cr
∴ t → w\cr}$$

I have the solution which shows

We start by noticing that we have **(How did we know we have to start here?)**
$$\displaylines{
u ∨ w; ¬w; ∴ u.\cr}$$

Indeed, if u ∨ w and ¬w are both true, then w is false, and u must be true.

Next
$$\displaylines{
u → ¬p; u; ∴ ¬p.\cr}$$

Indeed, if u → ¬p is true, either u is true and ¬p is true, or u is false. But
u is true, thus ¬p is true (Modus Ponens).

Then
$$\displaylines{
¬p → r ∧ ¬s; ¬p; ∴ r ∧ ¬s,\cr}$$

this is again Modus Ponens. Then
$$\displaylines{r ∧ ¬s; ∴ ¬s.\cr}$$

Indeed, for r ∧ ¬s to be true, it must be that ¬s is true. Finally **[Why can't let r to be false instead?)**

$$\displaylines{t → s; ¬s; ∴ ¬t\cr}$$

since for t → s to be true, we need either t to false, or t and s to be true,
but since s is false, t must be false (Modus Tollens), and

$$\displaylines{¬t ∴ ¬t ∨ w\cr}$$
or equivalently
$$\displaylines{¬t ∨ w ≡ t → w\cr}$$
using the Conversion theorem, which shows that the argument is valid.

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous, please check that I have edited it to say what you want.

Comment: @David Hi, thanks a lot first time here. It's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We start by noticing that we have (How did we know we have to start here?)

There is really no particular way you can know this, these problems generally involve a bit of trial and error.

> Indeed, for $r\wedge\neg s$ to be true, it must be that $\neg s$ is true. Finally (Why can't let $r$ to be false instead?)

$\wedge$ means "and": if $r\wedge\neg s$ is true then $r$ is true and $\neg s$ is true.

But anyway I think this is a very complicated solution.  Better: mark the statements (1), (2) etc, then

- assume $t$ is true;
- from (2), $s$ is true; therefore $r\wedge\neg s$ is false;
- from (1), $\neg p$ is false;
- from (3), $u$ is false;
- from (5), $w$ is true.

That is, assuming $t$ true shows $w$ true; so the hypothetical $t\to w$ is true.

In fact, one can say more: assuming $t$ is true we have $w$ true as above; but (4) says $w$ is false which is a contradiction.  So in fact $t$ is false, and this means that $t\to\langle\hbox{anything}\rangle$ is a valid conclusion!

Comment: Could you please help mark which statement are you referring to?

Comment: @MaTaKazer - he has simply marked the premises as : (1), (2), ... as you have done in your second post.

Comment: That's right.  Thanks @Mauro for clearing that up while I was off site.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion to be proved is (T --> W) which is equivalent to ~ (T & ~W) and to 
(~T v W). That makes of the rule " OR introduction" a posssible strategy.

The rule " OR Intro" is  : From any proposition X, infer  (X OR Y) 
(Y being also any proposition).

**How to find the strategy**? **We reason analytically, that is, we move backwards, from the desired result to its sufficient and necessary or sometimes to its simply sufficient conditions**, until we arrive at a condition that is given, in the premises.

Here 
(1) I want ~ T to use OR-Intro.
(2) To get ~ T I would need ~S 
(3) I won't get ~S alone, but I'll have both ~S and R. And to get them, I need ~P. 
(4) To get ~P, I need U 
(5) To get U I need ~W 
(6) ... **and I HAVE ~W.**

**The end of analysis is at the same time the beginning the proof.**

From ~W infer U ( using Disjunctive syllogism)

From U infer ~ P ( using Modus Ponens)

From ~ P infer (R & ~ S)   ( Using again Modus  Ponens)

From (R & ~ S) infer ~S    ( Using &-Elimination)

From (T --> S) and ~ S , infer ~ T  (  Using Modus Tollens)

From ~ T , infer ( ~ T v W)  ( Using OR-Intro)

From ( ~ T v W)  infer ( T --> W)  ( Using the définition of --> )

Answer (score 0):

> We start by noticing that we have **(How did we know we have to start here?)**

They, $\lnot w$ and $u\vee w$, are the only unconditional statements among the premises.   That makes them a useful place to start exploring.   We want to be able to derive from these either: the antecedent, or a negation of a consequent, of at least one among the conditional statements.   This will let us employ *modus ponens* or *modus tollens* (aka 'affirm the antecedent' and 'deny the consequent' respectively) to further derive something useful.   The *goal* is to derive $\lnot t$ from the premise $\lnot w$, from which we may deduce $\lnot w\to\lnot t$, and thus (via de Morgan's Law) $t\to w$.

In this case, $u$, can be derived by *disjunctive syllogism*, and this is the antecedent for $u\to\lnot p$.   Thus from there we may derive $\lnot p$, which is the antecedent for $\lnot p\to(r\land\lnot s)$, and allows the derivation of $r\land\lnot s$.   (Using *modus ponens*, or conditional elimination.)   Of course, from $r\land \lnot s$ we may derive $r$ and $\lnot s$ via simplification (aka conjunction elimination).   Of these, $\lnot s$ is the negation of the consequent for $t\to s$.   Thus we may derive our goal of $\lnot t$ via *modus tollens*.   Thus, as stated above, we can deduce $t\to w$.   $\blacksquare$

---

Now, we *could* have started with $t\to s$.   Since we were aiming to derive a conditional statement with $t$ as the antecedent, that is *also* a good starting point.   By assuming $t$ we could have picked through the premises and produced the following natural deduction proof.   This can also be produced by backtracking over the above process.

*So by assuming $t$ and using the premise $t\to s$, we may derive $s$ – via* modus ponens – *from which we may derive $\lnot(r\land\lnot s)$ – via an indirect proof.   Using that, and the premise, $\lnot p\to(r\land\lnot s)$, we may derive $\lnot\lnot p$ – via* modus tollens.   *Using that and the premise $u\to\lnot p$, we may derive $\lnot u$.   Using that and the premise $u\lor w$, we may derive $w$ – via disjunctive syllogism.   Hence $t\to w$ is deduced by discharging the assumption ($t$).*   $\blacksquare$

---

> Indeed, for r ∧ ¬s to be true, it must be that ¬s is true. Finally [Why can't let r to be false instead?)

Conjunction is logical "and".   $r\land \lnot s$ is true exactly when *both* $r$ and $\lnot s$ are true.   We are just not presently interested in the value of $r$.   We only need to use that $r\land\lnot s$ entails $\lnot s$.